# I have a syntax error and it doesnt make sense

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know why but i have a syntax error, my code looks completely fine to me,

```
$page = $_POST['page'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];



$Realpage = intval($page);
$Realamount = intval($amount);
$query = $con->prepare(
   "SELECT 
      * 
    FROM 
      store 
    AS 
      s
    INNER JOIN 
      product_pictures AS pp 
    ON 
      s.product_id = pp.id 
    INNER JOIN 
      product_name AS pn 
    ON 
      s.product_id = pn.id 
    WHERE 
      (s.product_price BETWEEN :firstPrice AND :secondPrice) AND 
      product_name LIKE :input LIMIT :page , :amount ");

$query->execute(array(':input' => "%" . $input . "%" , ":firstPrice" => intval($firstPrice), ":secondPrice" => intval($secondPrice) , ':page' => $Realpage * $Realamount, ':amount' => $Realamount));
```

Error:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0' , '20'' at line 1'

Comment: And the syntax error that it's giving you is???

Comment: And that error is what exactly?

Comment: Post the syntax error also.

Comment: > <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0' , '20'' at line 1'

Comment: it's just a name and it works perfectly, the part that doesn't work is the page and the amount part

Comment: You can't bind the limit values, without explicitly saying theey're integers

Comment: oh, should i just place them there or something?

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT and PAGE in your SQL cannot be part of statement preparation.

Comment: Thanks! I actually didn't know that, well now I'm using BindValue and it works!